# Styling For Loop Objects

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates

I want to achieve the design in the attached image with css. I'm a backend guy who is trying to learn frontend development.

I'm also using bootstrap in the project. I tried using the 'position:relative' but it's not working.

I'm building the site in Django.

HTML

```
 {% if hots %}
 {% for hot in hots %}   

  <img class="kown-image" src="{{hot.main_photo.url}}" width="300px" height="200px" />

 <p class="kown-prop"> <a href="{{ hot.get_absolute_url }}">{{ hot.name }}</a> </p>

 <p class="kown-cit"> {{ hot.city}},{{hot.country}}</p>

  {% with hot.motel_hr.first as md %}
                    {% if md %}
                  <p class="kown-cp">  From {{hot.user.user.currency}}{{ md.room_price }}/night </p>
                  <p class="kown-cop"> <a href="#">Buy Now</a></p>
            {% else %}
                     <p> no price found </p>

             {% endif %}
         {% endwith %}
         {% endfor %}


<p class="kown-down-line"> </p>      
 <p>  <a href="{% url 'haystack_search' %}?q={{query_string}}"/>See More Places </a></p>
 {% endif %}
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.kown-hotel{
    background-color:white; 
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:50px;   
  }

 .kown-image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 }

 .kown-prop {
   display:inline;
   vertical-align:top;
   padding-left:10px;
   width: 600px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color:green;
 }

 .kown-cit {
    background-color:black;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 305px;
    margin-top: -100px;
  }

   .kown-cp {
       float:right;
       margin-top: -90px;
   }

   .kown-cop {
      float:right;
      margin-top: -70px;
  }
```

It looks like the below screenshot in the browser with the css I wrote.

[image]

[image]

But I want it to align properly and look like the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What does your markup look like once compiled/output into a browser?

Comment: (…) 'cause CSS is for styling HTML elements, not Django templates ;) You can use http://www.bootply.com/new in addition to SO snippets (latter won't add Bootstrap CSS but it's guaranteed to last while bootply may disappear one day)

Answer (score 0):

Beside your `<img>` element, all your other containers are block elements, and therefor takes up 100% of the available width.

To get block elements to stay next to each other, you'll need to do two things:

1. First, set each of them to take up less space, so their total width will be no more than 100%.
2. Second, float them to the left so they will actually be on the same "row".

If you are planning on using Bootstrap, you can achieve that easily by using their column grid layout, for example:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <img src="..."/>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <p>Address</p>
  <p>Address</p>
  <p>Address</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <button>Buy now</button>
</div>
```

Read more about how to use bootstrap's grid layout here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: The images are overlapping on each other after adding col-xs-3 to the image. I added a class 'kown-image' and float them to the left.. still not working.

Comment: I was describing the general solution to your issue. Obviously if you want a specific overview of your problem, you will have to provide a working piece of code that has a problem. From your provided JPGs I can draw very little.

Comment: the post has been updated. See the screenshot from the browser and code.

Comment: This post is messy. My answer is no longer relevant to your current issues. Please revise your question and focus exactly on the problem you are having. Also - attach the result HTML - not just the template you are using in Django.